# What steps should I take to determine the root cause of linux server failure?

Tags: linux, troubleshooting

I am sorry if this question has been addressed before, I am assuming it has, but after a half hour of searching I couldn't find anything.

**Anyway, to the question:**

I am a windows guy and a self-taught programmer so I am very new to linux but am liking it more than Windows. We have a small Wordpress installation that fails seemingly at random. When I does I cannot SSH in and my only real option is to do a hard reboot from the Rackspace Cloud admin. It has always fixed the problem.

I want to know what I should be doing to determine what actually caused the problem though. This is a trivial example but we are planning on putting more applications on linux in the next year or so and I want to get to the point that I am comfortable dealing with problems in a more scientific way than "unplug it and plug it back in."

Where should I get started? I am open to books, blog posts, server fault questions, videos, seminars, college classes, anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

start with collecting statistics to see if there is any corelation of hangs and system activity. you can use for instance:

- [sar](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr) - fore pure text based stats
- [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) - for simple to get timeplots
- [cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) - like munin + much more, might be too much in your case

without such stats you are pretty much blind, they are also handy when you want to do some capacity planning or just want to see if there are any noticeable patterns/anomalies in behavior of your system.

start with monitoring [you'll have most 'out of the box' with munin]:

- load average
- cpu usage / io waits
- swapping activity
- number of http requests served
- network traffic
- free disk space on each partition
- ping response to the default gateway / some point of reference in the internet
- number of [my]sql queries

my best bet is that your machine is swapping do death/getting stuck with slow disk access but i might be very wrong.

things like complete system hangs probably did not leave much traces in your logs but in other situations - it's always worth checking content of syslog or specific application logs - maybe you've run out of space somewhere? maybe something segfaulted?

Comment: Don't forget to check the logs too - normally in /var/log

Answer (score 1):

This is a general recipe, it works not only on linux:

Identifing problems, in order:

1. remote login problems:

   1. network problems
   2. remote login daemon problems (sometime it can take minutes to login with ssh)
2. load problems (`uptime;df -h;free -m`)
3. read the logs (they are in `/var/log/`. System wide logs are `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/syslog`. In your case, you could be interested in `/var/log/apache`)

If you hard rebooted your server, be careful to write down the time you did it. So you could check the logs just before that time.

Comment: What is the best way to read the logs? Is there some tool that will present them in a (more) human readable format?

Comment: I usually use `less`, it's minimal, but a little more user friendly than `more`. It works in command line. Basically type `less /var/log/messages`, you can scroll up and down with arrows, you can search by typing `/text`, jump to next found with `n`, previous with `N` and go to end with `G`